# Estimating parameters of Von Mises Distribution Scipy - Inconsistent Answers

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability, probability-density

I am computing the parameters of a Von Mises distribution by hand and wanted to compare to the Scipy Von Mises fit function.

I am getting inconsistent results from the fit function.

My two datasets are d1 = [0.8pi,0.9pi] and d2 = [0.2pi,0.1pi]

My python function is below:

```
def calc(data):
    '''Takes a 1-D dataset and uses the scipy von mises to learn parameters and also calculates them by hand
    using the regular M.L estimation for mean and the bannerjee et al (2005) approximation for concentraion factor
    params: 1-D dataset in radians
    '''
    res = vonmises.fit(data, fscale=1)
    mu = np.arctan(sum(np.sin(data))/sum(np.cos(data)))
    A = sum(np.cos(data))*(1/len(data))*np.cos(mu)+sum(np.sin(data))*np.sin(mu)*(1/len(data))
    k = A*(2-A**2)/(1-A**2)
    print('mu and k by hand: ', mu, k)
    print('mu and k from fit function', res[1],res[0])
```

My results are as follows:

**Output:**

```
>d1:
mu and k by hand:  0.471238898038 41.3480495503
mu and k from fit function 0.471238858132 40.8666881759

>d2:
mu and k by hand:  -0.471238898038 -41.3480495503
mu and k from fit function 2.67035368203 40.8666556123
```

As you can see, the mu for d2 is different. The k has a different sign. 
d1 however is very similar.

I'm not sure why this discrepancy is occurring. I'm wondering if there is an issue with my estimation by hand. I'm using the M.L.E estimation from Bishop's Pattern recognition text book pg 109. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the calculation of `mu`:

```
mu = np.arctan(sum(np.sin(data))/sum(np.cos(data)))
```

`arctan` will only get you angles between -pi/2 and +pi/2. It does not know in which quadrant of the circle it is. Consider this: `arctan(1 / 1)` is the same as `arctan(-1 / -1)`. Both result in an angle of 45 deg but the latter should probably be 135 deg.

There is a different function, `arctan2`, which is aware of the both signs because it takes two arguments. This should give you the expected results:

```
mu = np.arctan2(sum(np.sin(data)), sum(np.cos(data)))
```

In general, when you need to do `arctan(y/x)` you usually want `arctan2(y, x)` unless you know in advance which range of angles to expect.